# Disable confirmation whether I copied or moved a VM in VMware

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

Is it possible to configure either a VM or VMware globally in such a way that it won't prompt me whether I moved or copied the VM?

This is the confirmation dialog I am interested in getting rid of:

[image: Confirmation dialog of VMware to ask whether a VM was moved or copied]

Background: I am using the same VM from both Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Windows 10, in both cases using the same VMware Workstation version (same as in same version number, but obviously the respective product for the OS). I checked some years ago with VMware and they said that was fine to do (in terms of licensing).

Alas, every time I switch the host OS, I get that prompt and I'd love to be able to somehow get rid of that. I understand approximately what the difference is between the two options (e.g. generating a new MAC address), but I'd like for a way to suppress it or tell VMware preemptively, if you will, that I moved it.

Comment: Set the following line in the .vmx file  uuid.action = "keep"     and test it. Word keep should be in double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alas, every time I switch the host OS, I get that prompt and I'd love to be able to somehow get rid of that. I understand approximately what the difference is between the two options (e.g. generating a new MAC address), but I'd like for a way to suppress it or tell VMware preemptively, if you will, that I moved it.

Within the the configuration file (.VMX) set **uuid.action =** to either **”create”** or **”keep”**.

> Note: If you want to change the Always Keep or Always Create setting, power off the virtual machine and edit its configuration file (.vmx). Delete the line that contains
>
> uuid.action = "create"
>
> or
>
> uuid.action = "keep"

Sources:

- [Changing or keeping a UUID for a moved virtual machine](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1541)
- [The UUID and Moving Virtual Machines](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_move_uuid_moving_virtual_machines.html)